# Bidirectional UDP traffic between GKE pod and GCE VM not routing

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, udp, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking

From a pod in GKE, a client subscribes to udp data. The server is in a GCE VM (not in GKE) in the same GCloud VPC.

The problem is that the data does not flow back to the pod.

Here is some of the code:

```
// Socket UDP
var subscriber = require('dgram').createSocket("udp4");

// Listen for message
subscriber.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  console.log("Subscriber got: " + msg + " from " + rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port);
});

// Subscribe
var message = Buffer.from('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","v_event":"event.to_listen_to","type_rpc":4}');
subscriber.send(message, 0, message.length, 4011, $vm_ip_address, function(err, bytes) {
  console.log('Subscribe Live Info Change');
});
```

I think that GKE does not know how to route the traffic from the VM to the pod. A load balancer is not an option as the data must come to the pod which subscribed.

Do you see a solution for this or UDP traffic is not fit for this architecture?

Comment: yes you are right gke dont know how to route traffic from VM to POD however if you are running single replica of behind any service you can expose service as LB but if single replica.

Comment: Is your `Pod` managed by a `Deployment` or maybe a [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) ? If its managed by `Deployment` all `Pods` within it are basically the same and there is no way to guarantee that the traffic is routed to the specific one. With `StatefulSet` you shouldn't have such problem as all `Pods` have unique identity and each of them can be reached by its specific DNS name.

Comment: @mario it has to be a deployment for scalability reasons. But as the traffic initiates from the pod, should NAT/conntrack do its job?

Comment: Hi @unludo ! Sorry for the late response. Did you manage to make it work during this time ? Well, as the traffic initiates from pod, I guess connection tracking should do its job and you don't need anything special to make it work. You may want to take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-networking-fundamentals) article which can help you in further debugging of the issue.